# Singleton Session Bean

Tags: java, ejb

I am trying to have a basic template for a single session bean. Then, I took the example included in the "The Architecture of the counter":

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ejb-basicexamples002.htm

However, when running the example, I am not able to print the value of count.hitCount.

I found the common problem when accessing the variable is not having the getter. For instance, in **index.html**:

```
<ui:define name="title">
        This page has been accessed #{count.hitCount} time(s).
</ui:define>
```

However, in the **Count.java** is including the getter getHitCount():

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Count implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private CounterBean counterBean;

    private int hitCount;

    public Count() {
        this.hitCount = 0;
    }

    public int getHitCount() {
        hitCount = counterBean.getHits();
        return hitCount;
    }
    public void setHitCount(int newHits) {
        this.hitCount = newHits;
    }
```

Finally, the **CounterBean.java** increases the variable:

```
@Singleton
public class CounterBean {
    private int hits = 1;

    // Increment and return the number of hits
    public int getHits() {
        return hits++;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help and comments, they are highly appreciated.

Comment: What is actually happening? "I am not able to print the value of count.hitCount." does not tell us anything useful.

Comment: `Count` should be `@RequestScoped`. And increment the `CounterBean.hits` value by `CounterBen.incHits()` in `Count.initialize()` (annotated by `@PostConstruct`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The facelet with a counter of times it got displayed:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
  <h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
  <h:body>
    This page displayed #{counterController.hitCount} times.
  </h:body>
</html>
```

The `CounterController` is a `@RequestScoped` bean to increment the `CounterBean.hitCount` in its `@PostConstruct` method:

```
package x;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

@Named( value = "counterController" )
@RequestScoped
public class counterController
{

  @EJB
  private CounterBean counterBean;

  @PostConstruct
  public void initialize()
  {
    counterBean.incHitCount();  
  }

  public int getHitCount()
  {
    return counterBean.getHitCount();
  }

  public CounterController()
  {
  }

}
```

`CounterBean` is a `@Singleton` EJB to store the hitCount. `@StartUp` annotation do it an eagerly constructed bean (created on application startup, before any client request accepted):

```
package x;

import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import lombok.Data;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class CounterBean
{
  private int hitCount;

  public int getHitCount()
  {
    return hitCount;
  }

  public void incHitCount()
  {
    hitCount++;
  }

  public CounterBean()
  {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and time, it is working as expected. Cheers